# tracking the flow of classes called while debugging the project

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I have a query that is I am debuging a project in eclipse and I have to enchance its functionality in near future the project is in mostly in core java and all the classes are interlinked in the whole flow.

As i am debuging the project so as per the flow it is switiching between different classes now I want to record all the claases name from which it pass , so in order to remember the flow so thatr is the one way , so for this either I can go for logs, or is there any softwate or plugin that can be installed in eclipse that record to which varios classes I passesand which methods were called in which order other thanm logs please advise.

Comment: When you debug and stop at breakpoint you should be able to see the whole stack of methods called.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best thing is to log the relevant information you need.

Logs have the advantage of recording exactly what you need (So not only the names of the class you traverse but also relevant variable values) and you can run them even outside from Eclipse, which it is sometimes useful when you have to track down bugs in the production environment.

Comment: Thanks a lot also please advise shall i put log.debug every where I want and upon debuging the application i can cross check the debug statements inside the log